# Using a list for filtering private IP's from DestinationPrefix in route table?

Tags: powershell

Trying to filter some private IP addresses out of the route table to get the remainder from `Get-NetRoute`.

Tried to use array and PowerShell regex methods (not really keen on regex methods) from some list examples via Google but although there was no error it did not work out. The below code line is what I'm presently using and it works exactly how I expected it to work.

```
Get-NetRoute |
    ? AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4' |
    ? DestinationPrefix -notlike '0.0.*' |
    ? DestinationPrefix -notlike '10.*' |
    ? DestinationPrefix -notlike '128.*' |
    ? DestinationPrefix -notlike '255.*' |
    ? DestinationPrefix -notlike '127.*' |
    ? DestinationPrefix -notlike '224.0.*' |
    ? NextHop -notlike '0.0.*' |
    ? RouteMetric -eq '0'
```

Although that code line works, it's really long and I'd like to shorten it. Is there a way to use some sort of list instead of putting everything in one line with the multiple `? DestinationPrefix -notlike` s so it looks something like this `? DestinationPrefix -notlike <list here>` instead of the individual `? DestinationPrefix` for each IP item to filter out?

Answer (score 1):

This would shorten it a bit:

```
Get-NetRoute | ? {
    $_.AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4' -and
    $_.DestinationPrefix -notmatch '^(0\.0|10|128|255|127|224\.0)\.' -and
    $_.NextHop -notlike '0.0.*' -and
    $_.RouteMetric -eq '0'
}
```

Comment: yes that did shorten it a bit. Was getting too many 'DestinationPrefix -notlike' s to keep track of :) Thank you very much